# What is the pattern for 'instead of x, y...'

Tags: grammar

For example, how would I say, 'instead of x, we should do y'?
I find it hard to balance the sentence correctly in chinese.

Do I need to use, 反而 or 而且? Or is there some better method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**反而** is mostly used when something is *contrary to expectations*.
An example: Suppose it is predicted that there would be no wind, but there is a lot of wind, and after a while it starts to blow even harder you can say:

```
风不但没停，反而越刮越大了
    the wind not only hasn't stopped, but blowing harder and harder
```

**而且** is used to give some extra information and is typically translated as "*and also; besides; and what's more; but also".

You can use "**而不是**". For example:

```
我们需要的是能力强的职工，而不是吃干饭的
    What we need are people with great capabilities, instead of those who live off others.
```

You can also use **与其**..., **不如**... which is translated as *rather than ... , you'd better ...*.
An example:
    与其少买，不如不买
        I'd rather not buy anything at all than buy just a few.

Often Chinese wouldn't use a conjunction at all. For example (these 2 examples come from Nciku)

```
中国人不习惯用刀叉，更喜欢用筷子
    Chinese people prefer to use chopsticks instead of a knife and fork.    

我想上场，不想在余下的比赛中做替补。
    I want to play instead of spend the rest of the match on this bench.
```

Comment: So its sound better to use 而不是 and reverse the positions of x and y.  In english it doesn't matter where x and y appear as 'instead' can start a sentence or end with it. In chinese it has to balance with 而不是 in the 2nd clause.

Answer (score 1):

Instead can also be used in the "rather than" situation 
Like, rather than A, why don't we do B
與其做A, 我們不如做B